# Will this command run if connection to the remote server is lost?

Tags: nohup, sleep

If I run a command like this on my remote server:

```
$ sleep 3h ; date ; nohup long-running-process ; date
```

... and the connection is lost after 2 hours, will the full command be executed?

And if not, how can I modify the command to make sure everything will run even if the connection is lost?

Comment: No, everything past `sleep 3h` will not be run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, because the connection will disconnect and send a SIGHUP signal to all the child processes connected to the terminal during the `sleep` command, before the `nohup` is processed.

If you need to run a command at a specific time, you could:

- put your commands in a script, and nohup the script.
- use an [`at` job](https://tecadmin.net/one-time-task-scheduling-using-at-commad-in-linux/) for one-time needs
- use a [`cron` job](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) for periodic jobs
- use [`tmux`](http://tmux.github.io) or [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) to persist your terminal across connections to the server.

As the old saying goes, there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim, very comprehensive! I went with cron in the end.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.  That's what we're here for. :)